# Need Scrollable (Dynamic loading), Sortable, Async fetched table

Tags: gwt, scroll, widget

I have DataGrid in mind, making use of AsyncDataProvider and tweaking the ScrollBar behaviour, but it's proving to be a pain to access the datagrid scrollbar and tweak it the way I want.

Anyone have some other ideas, of a widget I could use that fills these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The SmartGWT library has something called LiveGrid. I think that is what you are looking for. Check out the showcase on the SmartGWT site:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_grid_live